# Multi-Client / Multi-Server Network View

Tags: c#, network-programming, network-protocols

Implementing a huge Multi-Client / Multi-Server Network View
Say we have just 4 clients with IDs 1 , 2 , 3 , 4
We have also 3 Servers with IDs A , B , C
Initially Clients 1 , 2 chose Server A & Client 3 chose Server B & Client 4 chose Server  C
Here we are :
[ 1 , 2 => A ] , [ 3 => B ] , [ 4 => C ]
Suddenly , Server C broke down !!

**Question**
What's the best method to make clients Initially finding there suitable server to establish TCP/IP connection with it ? & Finding another Server if connected one was broken ?

Note :
Initially [ 1 , 2 => A ] as A is the closest Server
BUT
Client 4 MUST choose Server B even A was more closer !! Population limitations => Connection priority constrain ..,

Regards ..,

Comment: It's unclear how or why 2 connects to A and not B, and therefore why B connects to 3 and C connects to 4. Once that logic is understood, perhaps the rest of the question can be understood. You might also want to explain what is "closest" to 3 if B breaks down - is it A or C?

Comment: Done , Is it now clear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put server A/B/C behind a load-balancer and put the sessions, if you have any, in the database. If server B stops working, the request will be routed to A and C.

Comment: What do you mean by load-balancer as I got it a dispatcher ?  
What's its architecture ?  
Can I implements this point of view as a P2P based on DHT tables ?